# React Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa)

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have the next constructor in a React Component

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      socket:null,
      state:'main',
      match:{
        creationDate:'',
        host:'',
        players:[]
      },
      name1:'',
      name2:'',
    }
```

Then I define an Input like this:

```
<Input style={{width: 100 + '%'}} readOnly value={this.state.match.host}></Input>
```

And I am getting the next Warning:
Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

As far as I know it's just needed to define the initial value of the variable state as I did.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does that `Input` element look like? Where does it come from?

Comment: I am using reactstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `value` you are providing the input changes from `undefined` to some string. This makes React think you are switching between an uncontrolled input (value = `undefined`) to a controlled one.

One workaround is to switch the `value` to `defaultValue`, and to add a `key` prop with the same value like this:

`<Input style={{width: 100 + '%'}} readOnly defaultValue={this.state.match.host} key={this.state.match.host}></Input>`

The changing `key` will make sure that the input is re-rendered with the updated `defaultValue` each time it changes.

Alternatively, try and figure out why you are passing `undefined` to the input `value` at the first place.

Comment: I tried using defaultVaue as a solution but then i want the change the value if the input and it stays the same. I am printing the value that i am passing from the beggining and it is always defined as an empty string.

Comment: Does adding `key={this.state.match.host}` to your input solve this? (Keep on using `defaultValue`) This should make sure the input will re-render on each value change.

Comment: Perfect! I've updated my answer with the `key` solution so you can approve it.